# when I tried to send a two or more json files in express. It shows an error "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

Tags: node.js, express

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
> to the client
> at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)
> at ServerResponse.header (E:\download\react-native\chat app\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
> at ServerResponse.send (E:\download\react-native\chat app\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
> at ServerResponse.json (E:\download\react-native\chat app\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
> at E:\download\react-native\chat app\backend\routes\Routes.js:183:40
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {   code:
> 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT' }

The code:

```
app.post("/images", (req, res) => {
    const uname = req.body.userName;
    FreindRequest.find({ $and: [{ acceptance: "accept" }, { $or: [{ reciever: uname }, { sender: uname }] }] }).then(
        users => {
            if (users) {
                users.map(user => {
                    ImageModel.find({ $or: [{ userName: user.sender }, { userName: user.reciever }] }).then(user => {
                        if (user) {
                            res.json(user);
                        }
                        else {
                            res.json({ error: "error" })
                        }
                    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
                })
            }
            else {
                res.json({ error: "error" });
            }
        }
    ).catch(err => res.json({ error: "error" }));
});
```

Comment: why do you want to return a response for each user `find` query? If you do that how can you get the execution control back to execute the next user element? You are using `res.json()` so many places needlessly and that is what causing the problem.
And why are you writing a post request to find the records, post request should save the data. I don't see anywhere in the code saving the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can send only one response for one request. So you should not use res.json() inside map function.

If you want to send multiple JSON . You can create an array inside an function and then push all the data and send res.json() after map function like below.

```
app.post("/images",async (req,res)=>{ 
  const uname=req.body.userName; 
  FreindRequest.find({$and:[{acceptance:"accept"},{$or:[{reciever:uname},{sender:uname}]}]})
  .then( users=>{ 
    if(users){ 
      let userImages = []
      await users.map(user=>{ 
        ImageModel.find({$or:[{userName:user.sender},{userName:user.reciever}]})
        .then(user=>{ 
          if(user){ 
            userImages.push(user)
          } else { 
            res.json({error:"error"}) 
          }
        })
        .catch(err=>res.json({error:"error"})); 
      })
      res.json(userImages)  
    } else { 
      res.json({error:"error"}); 
    }
  })
  .catch(err=>res.json({error:"error"})); 
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help. but when I execute the code like the way you told.it returns empty array i don't know the reason and also the execution begins at the bottom and goes up i realize this when "console.log" before the userImage.push(user) and after have the same result([]) .

Comment: app.post("/images",async (req,res)=>{const uname=req.body.userName; const userImage=[]
    FreindRequest.find({$and:[{acceptance:"accept"},{$or:[{reciever:uname},{sender:uname}]}]}).then((users)=>{ if(users){
        await users.map((user)=>{ 
        ImageModel.find({$or:[{userName:user.sender},{userName:user.reciever}]}).sort({date:-1}).then( user=>{ 
            if(user){userImage.push(user)
            }else {res.json({error:"error"})}
          }).catch(err=>console.log(err))})
    }else{res.json({error:"error"})}
      res.json(userImage)}).catch(err=>res.json({error:"error"}))})